# Add to values of a DataFrame using cooridnates

Tags: python, dataframe, increment, series

I have a dataframe a:

```
Out[68]: 
      p0_4    p5_7    p8_9  p10_14     p15  p16_17  p18_19  p20_24  p25_29  \
0   1360.0   921.0   676.0  1839.0   336.0   668.0   622.0  1190.0  1399.0   
1    308.0   197.0   187.0   411.0    67.0   153.0   172.0   336.0   385.0   
2     76.0    59.0    40.0    72.0    16.0    36.0    20.0    56.0    82.0   
3    765.0   608.0   409.0  1077.0   220.0   359.0   342.0   873.0   911.0   
4   1304.0   906.0   660.0  1921.0   375.0   725.0   645.0  1362.0  1474.0   
5    195.0   135.0    78.0   262.0    44.0    97.0   100.0   265.0   229.0   
6   1036.0   965.0   701.0  1802.0   335.0   701.0   662.0  1321.0  1102.0   
7   5072.0  3798.0  2865.0  7334.0  1399.0  2732.0  2603.0  4976.0  4575.0   
8   1360.0   962.0   722.0  1758.0   357.0   710.0   713.0  1761.0  1660.0   
9    743.0   508.0   369.0  1118.0   286.0   615.0   429.0   738.0   885.0   
10  1459.0  1015.0   679.0  1732.0   337.0   746.0   677.0  1493.0  1546.0   
11   828.0   519.0   415.0  1057.0   190.0   439.0   379.0   788.0  1024.0   
12  1042.0   690.0   503.0  1204.0   219.0   451.0   465.0  1193.0  1406.0   

     p30_44   p45_59  p60_64   p65_74  p75_84  p85_89  p90plus  
0    4776.0   8315.0  2736.0   5463.0  2819.0   738.0    451.0  
1    1004.0   2456.0   988.0   2007.0  1139.0   313.0    153.0  
2     291.0    529.0   187.0    332.0   108.0    31.0     10.0  
3    2807.0   5505.0  2060.0   4104.0  2129.0   516.0    252.0  
4    4524.0   9406.0  3034.0   6003.0  3366.0   840.0    471.0  
5     806.0   1490.0   606.0   1288.0   664.0   185.0    108.0  
6    4127.0   8311.0  2911.0   6111.0  3525.0  1029.0    707.0  
7   16917.0  27547.0  8145.0  15950.0  9510.0  2696.0   1714.0  
8    5692.0   9380.0  3288.0   6458.0  3830.0  1050.0    577.0  
9    2749.0   5696.0  2014.0   4165.0  2352.0   603.0    288.0  
10   4676.0   7654.0  2502.0   5077.0  3004.0   754.0    461.0  
11   2799.0   4880.0  1875.0   3951.0  2294.0   551.0    361.0  
12   3288.0   5661.0  1974.0   4007.0  2343.0   623.0    303.0
```

and a series d:

```
Out[70]: 
2     p45_59
10    p45_59
11    p45_59
```

Is there a simple way to add 1 to number in a with the same index and column labels in d?

I have tried:

```
a[d] +=1
```

However this adds 1 to every value in the column, not just the values with indices 2, 10 and 11.

Thanking you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to try this.

```
a.loc[list(d.index), list(d.values)] += 1
```